# Unable to check Authentification in LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to login throught LDAP.

```
<?php
$credentials = array();
$credentials[] = ['username' => 'johnDoe', 'password' => 'SECRET'];
$credentials[] = ['username' => 'Joe', 'password' => 'SECRET2'];

$ldapconfig['usersdn'] = 'cn=users';
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=super,dc=ds,dc=domain,dc=com';
foreach($credentials as $key => $value){
    $ldap=ldap_connect("example.com");
    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
    if(ldap_error($ldap) == "Success"){
        if (@ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) {
            @ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
            //$ldapBindServer = @ldap_bind($ldap, $value['username'], $value['password']);
            $dn="uid=".$value['username'].",".$ldapconfig['usersdn'].",".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
            $ldapBindServer = @ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $value['password']);
            var_dump($ldapBindServer); // false
        }
    }else{
        echo "ldap_error: " . ldap_error($ldap);
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $value['username'] , $value['password']);
        if (!$bind) { 
            echo "ldap_error: " . ldap_error($ldap);
        }else{
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
    ldap_close($ldap);
}
```

Output :

```
boolean false
boolean false
```

I don't understand why I can't check the auth, the credentials are correct. Is there something wrong ? Is there a way to debug with more information ?

Comment: $value is empty. So there are no credentials used.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Fixed

Comment: What about **NOT** suppress errors removing the @ in `@ldap_bind();`.

Comment: here is the output : `Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in`

Comment: Sounds like there is a networking problem, or maybe you got the address of the server wrong or something.

Comment: Why is `ldap_error($ldap)` giving me `Success` ?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php), it returns the status of the last LDAP command you ran. But the last command you ran was ldap_set_option, not ldap_connect, so it's likely to be reporting the status of that. Also the documentation specifically says _"Never check for a specific error message text, but always use an error number to check."_ ...so why are you checking for a piece of text, and not a number? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-errno.php should be used in the `if`.

Comment: Another reason it seems to succeed could also be that (again, as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php), ldap_connect does not actually open a connection! Instead it just checks that the supplied connection details look correct. It does not actually initiate the connection until that is required by another command, so there would be no way for it to know at that time whether there is a network problem or not. That is probably why you don't experience a problem until you call ldap_bind().